# Log/list bandwidth usage by file on NGINX?

Tags: nginx, monitoring, bandwidth

Is it possible to produce a list or log of the bandwidth usage by file on NGINX? Something like:

```
BANDWIDTH USAGE LAST 7 DAYS by FILE;

\Project.zip 1.8 GB
\Docu8ment.doc 350 MB
\logo.png 238 MB
\style.css 72 MB
```

Answer (score 0):

nginx produces `access.log` files with common log format. Common log format files can be analysed with different utilities, for example Webalizer and AWStats.

Those can generate statistics that you are looking for.

Comment: awstats does that? Amazing i gotta try!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this will work if you use it in a crontab ?

> cd /rootDir/ for FILE in *; do
>
> count=$(grep -c $FILE /var/log/nginx/access.log)
>
> size=$(du $FILE | cut -f1)
>
> BW4File=$((count * size))
>
> echo $FILE $BW4File"K"
>
> done

Comment: I found out why awstats and goaccess wouldn't work for me. The bytes are entirely missing from the log. Because downloads are started using nginx header X-Accel-Redirect there must be an issue somewhere else. but i'll award you for replying even though i can't test it.

Comment: Thanks man! I hope you get to test it. It calculates the size of yout files using du and multiplies it by the number of times it has been requested. It worked for me